# Is it reasonable to ask for a cost of living raise

Tags: salary, cost-of-living

If the company moves to the other side of the city and I move with it so as not to deal with traffic and just generally be more convenient for me, and if the rent/gas/other costs of living are higher in that section (it's a nicer part of town), can I reasonably ask for a raise since I am moving only because the company is?

Comment: Just a note on terminology so you don't go confusing anyone you talk to about this - [Cost of Living](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_living) and pay changes relating to it very specifically refer to **inflation**. As pointed out in a comment, this isn't a change in the cost of living, this is a change in cost of *lifestyle*.

Comment: Changing where you live is your choice. The company's office move is. You are in a much better negotiating position if you don't relocate where you're living.

Comment: That is not a COLA raise

Comment: @alroc what do you mean I'd be in a better position? A better position for what?

Comment: @wicbuj a better position for asking for more money. If you weren't moving, you could say to the company "you moved the office, now it costs me more to come to work. I think we need to revisit our terms." Maybe instead of getting more money, you could negotiate working remotely one day per week.

Comment: Whenever a company moves offices, they always get a number of people quitting. It's a good time to put pressure on them for a raise, quite apart from any question of cost of living in the "nicer part of town".

Comment: @AakashM I think you've potentially confused things further. A cost of living raise or COLA is a specific term that's intended to preserve buying power in the face of inflation. But the OP is correctly referring to a change in his cost of living in function of location.

Answer (score 10):

Normally I would think not, you're not moving because the company is, you're moving for your own convenience. Plenty of people commute quite long distances and don't get paid more because of it.

However it can't hurt to ask, since it would depend wholly on the specific companies outlook on such a situation.

Comment: I second this. Cost of Living isn't rising, the cost of your lifestyle is changing. You've admitted it's convenience, it's not necessary. If the company asked you to move, then yes you would have a basis to negotiate for any change in cost or to cover moving expenses, but from what's been put in the question - I'd say you'll be denied fairly promptly.

Comment: Depends on the Company, if the commute costs are more than the permanent moveing costs company's in my Country would even pay a considarable amount if it would actually lower monthly commute costs

Comment: @Thomo umm, perhaps you ought to travel more, because most regular folks would say otherwise. I wish it was just less competition, but a lot of financial deadweight is forcing prices artificially higher.

Comment: @clifton_h - what are you talking about? Cost of Living is a very specific term, and in regards to this question CoL isn't changing, the cost of the persons lifestyle, at their own choice, is.

Comment: @Thomo fair enough. Still, why be so concerned to ask complete strangers? Perhaps  It should read is asking for a raise rude?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly ask for a compensation for the fact that your commute costs more. I work in a heavily unionized industry and when one of our locations moved to the other end of the city, everyone who was found to now have a longer commute got an upgrade to that distance on their public transport ticket paid by the company.

However, where you are living is completely up to you. If you can still reach the company by normal transport, the company will likely write this off as "your problem".

So it cannot hurt to ask, but even if successful don't expect riches. Expect to be reimbursed for the actual cost of the commute from your old home, not the fancy new house next to the company premises.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's reasonable to ask the question.

A location move by the company is not your choice, but there are lots of ways in which it could impact your life and finances including:

1. Fuel costs, public transport costs
2. Extended childcare hours (costs)
3. Loss of personal social time

However, whether the company decides to give a pay rise to help offset these extra costs is a decision for the company.

There is one other area to investigate. Your employment contract. Most employment contracts will state the location you are to perform your duties. Changes to this should also have involved an element of consultation with you,which is your opportunity to raise exactly these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask whatever you wanna ask.  But in kind, be prepared for your employer to give whatever answer.

If you move -- by your own words -- the company is not the only part that's benefiting.  It's in a "nice" part of town (your words) -- but you are yet ungrateful.  Ultimately, *you* must pay for your happiness.  Relish in the good things on the better side of town, as you may benefit in ways you haven't even imagined yet.